# How to use container parameter with Bootstrap popover plugin

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I basically have a button group with one button that is sometimes disabled ("Corpus delicti"). In the case it is disabled I want to show the user an explanation via a popover.

Since disabled elements require wrapper elements I wrapped a div around the button - what messed the styling up.

So I followed Bootstrap's hint "to specify the option container: 'body'" but styling is still messed up.

This is the markup, find it also in this fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/7ben7zmg/

```
<div class="btn-group" role="group">
  <button onclick="console.log('huh')" type="button" class="btn btn-default">Log-Datei</button>
  <div class="btn-group" role="group">
    <div data-container="body" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="right" data-content="Lorem ipsum..." data-trigger="hover" data-html="true">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" disabled=""></button>
    </div>
    Corpus delicti <span class="caret"></span>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="../../createStuff/1/123/de" target="_blank">deutsch</a></li>
      <li><a href="../../createStuff/1/123/en" target="_blank">englisch</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="btn-group" role="group">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Infoseite <span class="caret"></span></button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="#">deutsch</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">englisch</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">TCP-Dump</button><button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Diesen Kunden deaktivieren</button>
</div>
```

Have no clue what I can do. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apply `data-toggle:popover` in the `btn-group` instead of wrapping in other div..

Wrapping to another div will disturb your layout..

**[Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bhuwanb9/8xg49y8m/)**

Comment: Great. Thank you!